# SBT Plugins: Is it possible to run scripted for a single test instead of running all tests?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I have 5 [scripted](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing-sbt-plugins.html) tests to test my sbt plugin. All of them take long to run. I sometimes want to run just one of the tests.

**Is it possible to specify to scripted which test to run?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pass the path of the test as an argument to the `scripted` command.

For example, to run a test in *<project>/src/sbt-test/foo/bar*, run `scripted foo/bar` from sbt:

```
> scripted foo/bar
```

Comment: or `> scripted foo/*` to run all tests under `foo` folder